# C# , Read every row of a string array with Directory.GetFiles

Tags: c#, arrays

I read a folder which contain many **.txt** files and I need get the names of all these files.
So I have create the below function:

```
var targetDirectory = @"\\192.168.1.175\user\HST\";
string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);

for (int i = 0; i < fileEntries.Length; i++) 
{
     string testFile = fileEntries[i];

     string test;
     test = testFile;
}
```

> The variable test is only point to set a `breakpoint`.

My problem is that if I set a `breakpoint` before the `for` loop my variable `fileEntries` contains 16 rows and it's OK. 
When I set a `breakpoint` in the variable `test` I can not see the value of the `testFile`.

But, if I set `testFile = fileEntries[4]` , it works without any problem.

Could someone help me with this?

**EDIT :**
This is the image with all rows of my array

[image: array result]

Comment: Consider `EnumerateFiles` rather than `GetFiles` to avoid allocating the array. Also consider using `foreach` rather than `for`.

Comment: `When i set a breakpoint in test i can't see the value of testFile.` Which _exact_ line is the breakpoint on?

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not clear what you're trying to do. You get a list of files in a directory... good What is it you're trying to do with this list of files?

Comment: the breakpoint is on string test, so i can see the value of string testFile = fileEntries[i];

Comment: @Jamiec inside the for loop (or foreach) i need read all rows inside all files of the foldrer

Comment: `the breakpoint is on string test, ` Do you mean `string test;`?

Comment: Ok, so whats the problem? If this is a console app try just writing `Console.WriteLine(testFile);` inside the for loop and you'll see each path. Your problem is still entirely unclear

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. The different indentation makes me concerned there may be a scoping issue involved.

Comment: @Jamiec My problem is inside the loop testFile hasn't a value.

Comment: Given the code here, I assure you it does! See the comment above your last one. There is more to this problem than you're currently showing us so we cant answer it!

Comment: @Jamiec its a asp.net core project

Comment: ok, so write out the array to an HTML element, or to a webapi endpoint or somewhere that lets you inspect it. (Or, just use the debugger/Immediate/watch windows)

Comment: @Jamiec i have update the post with all rows of the array from degugger

Comment: So all you've done is proven my point that the array (and therefore the variable holding each element within the loop) has data. This still doesn't help us answer your question (which I'm still not sure what the actual question is!)

Comment: @Jamiec Inside a loop i want read every single row

Comment: Yes, you've already done that. Within your loop the variable `testFile` holds the path to the current file.

Comment: @Jamiec this is the right problem, testFile never get a value

Comment: Impossible with the code you've shown. Sorry, C# just can't break like that. Show us a [mcve] or this is 100% unanswerable.

Comment: In short - we don't believe you. One of two things is occurring. a) What you are saying isn't happening. _Or_ b) What you are saying _is_ happening but the code you are running is different to what you have showed us. This is why we are asking for a [mcve].

Comment: Theres a (sort of) third option. c) The debugger is showing you not what you expect due to a race condition. Closely related to b)

Comment: A literal screenshot of your IDE showing the lines of code in your question (and preferably lines above and below) would prove, or disprove, my guess that b) is the cause. Not optimal, but it may allow us to focus on the real problem faster.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are debugging a release build of the application.

For a release build, the following code from your sample:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < fileEntries.Length; i++) {
        string testFile = fileEntries[i];

        string test;
        test = testFile;
    }
```

Gets turned into:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)fileEntries.Length; i++) {
            string str = fileEntries[i];
    }
```

As you can see, `testFile` has been removed entirely, which makes it impossible to see in the debugger.

Ensure that you're debugging a DEBUG build.

The Advanced Build Settings for your build should have "Debugging information" set to "Full".

Also in the general build settings, ensure that "Optimize code" is NOT selected.